# An integral related to inner product over unit ball?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $B(0,1)$ be the unit ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a point, how can we compute the following integral
$$\int_{B(0,1)}e^{-\langle x,y\rangle}dx,$$
where $\langle-,-\rangle$ is the standard inner product of $\mathbb{R}^n.$

I try to use Fubini's Theorem, but I don't get the inductive form.